# Add 2 columns in a row in csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to have 2 columns in every row in a csv file using php, but I only get one column, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
        $csvLinks = array();

        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $csvLinks = $this->request->data['csvLinks'];
        }

        $col = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($csvLinks); $i+=2) {
            array_push($col, $csvLinks[$i]);
            array_push($col, $csvLinks[$i+1] .",");
        }

       foreach($col as $row) {
           fputcsv($fp, explode(',',$row));
       }
```

the result I'm getting looks like the following

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to have multiple columns in a single line, you have to have an array per line. So you have to have an array(columns) inside an array (lines).

Do it like this:

```
$csvLinks = array();

        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $csvLinks = $this->request->data['csvLinks'];
        }

        $lines = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($csvLinks); $i+=2) {
            // Make a columns array
            $col = array();
            // Push the values inside the columns array
            array_push($col, $csvLinks[$i]);
            array_push($col, $csvLinks[$i+1]);
            // push the columns array inside the $lines array
            array_push($lines, $col);
        }

       foreach($lines as $line) {
           fputcsv($fp, $line);
       }
```